# positioning webkit-scrollbar absolute and vertically center

Tags: html, css, scroll, webkit

I want to make responsive menu. On mobile I want to allow a scrollable menu, and I need to make it with default scrollbar. I want these scroll arrows make vertically centered on my menu, but I dont know how. There's my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/ofjwe6jp/) (green and red is arrows, what I replace with images)

There is my webkit-scrollbar CSS

```
#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar{    
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   background: transparent;
   z-index: 300;
}

#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-button{}

#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-button:increment{
   background: red;
}

#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-button:decrement{
   background: green;
}
```

Comment: check my answer below. let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think you can position text on top of the scroll bar. so my solution is you don't use a scroll bar ( set `overflow:hidden` ) and instead use 2 buttons that act like a scroll bar ( click on left, scrolls to left, click on right goes to right.) because that's essentially what you want, right ?

presuming you can't change the HTML structure ( write inside the HTML ) i added the `.previous` and `.next`  buttons with JQ

then, using [scrollLeft()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/) method, i achieved the desired behaviour.

let me know if this is what you want.

see snippet below :

```js
$('<span class="previous"></span>').prependTo("#page")
$('<span class="next"></span>').appendTo("#page")

$(".previous").click(function(){
     var posLeft = $(".page-nav").scrollLeft();
  $(".page-nav").animate({scrollLeft: posLeft - 200}, 500);

})
$(".next").click(function(){
     var posLeft = $(".page-nav").scrollLeft();
  $(".page-nav").animate({scrollLeft: posLeft + 200}, 500);

})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');

a{text-decoration:none;}

#page{
  position:relative;
  font-family:"Roboto";
  font-weight:100;
  font-size:13px;
}

#page .page-nav{
    background: white;
    position:relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}

#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar{    
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 300;
}

#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-button{}

#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-button:increment{
    background: red;
}

#page .page-nav::-webkit-scrollbar-button:decrement{
    background: green;
}

#page .page-nav .items{
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#page .page-nav .items .scroll-right, #page .page-nav .items .scroll-left{
    content: "";
    background-image: url(../images/sort.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 9px;
    width: 9px;
    height: 12px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 200;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#page .page-nav .items:after{
    content: '';
    width: 200px;
    height: 31px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left ,transparent -0px, white);
    z-index: 100;
}

#page .page-nav .item{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 6px 15px;
}

#page .page-nav .item a{color:#333333;}

#page .page-nav .item.current a{
    color: #0099ff;
}


/* NEW CSS */

span {
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999;
}
span.previous {
  background:red;
  left:0;
}
span.next {
  background:green;
  right:0;
  
}
#page { position:relative;}
.page-nav { padding-left:15px;padding-right:25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div class="page-nav">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 1</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 2</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 3</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 4</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 5</a></div>
            <div class="item current"><a href="">Menu item 6</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 7</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 8</a></div>
            <div class="item"><a href="">Menu item 9</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. i added new CSS on the bottom of your CSS . i didn't delete yours. so you might want to clean it up if you use this solution.

Comment: yeah, It works nicely, there's gonna be a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eatmailyo/ofjwe6jp/1/ for other peoples :) thanks